# Supremum and infimum: proving with definition

Tags: real-analysis, limits

I tried to solve following task, but I am not sure whether my solution is correct. Quest: Find supremum and infimum $$A=\left\{\frac{n - k^2}{n^2 + k^3}:n,k \in \mathbb{N} \right\}$$My attempt:
 By substituting some numbers we see that $sup(A)=\frac{1}{5}$ and $inf(A)=-\frac{1}{5}$. Now we need to check it with definition. We need to check if: $$\forall _{n,k \in\mathbb{N}}   \frac{1}{5}>\left(\frac{n - k^2}{n^2 + k^3}\right)$$ From this we get $n^2+k^3>5n-5k^2 \Rightarrow n(n-5)>-k^2(k+5)$ what is true, since for all $n>5$ left side is positive and right side is  always negative. I think that up to $n=5$ it can be done by hand (is it enough to formally prove the first part of definition of supremum?). Second part of definition requires:$$\forall_{\epsilon>0}\exists_{n_{0}, k_{0}\in \mathbb{N}} \frac{1}{5} -\epsilon<\frac{n_{0} - k_{0}^2}{n_{0}^2 + k_{0}^3}\Rightarrow ...\Rightarrow\epsilon>F(n,k)$$
And from Archimedes we know that it is enough to take $\epsilon>[F(n,k)]+1$. 
Is it true? I am not sure, because for supremum $\frac{1}{4}$ also works in definition. (Or the argument of checking manually is enough to eliminate the idea of $sup(A)=\frac{1}{4}$ ?). And the same for infimum. Does it go the same way? Thanks in advance!

Comment: *By substituting some numbers we see that*... Do we? How?

Comment: Checking for $n=1, k=i, 0<i<5$ etc.?

Comment: And what about $n\gt1$? Very strange...

Comment: Why strange? by etc i mean the same for $k=1, n=i, 0<i<5$

Comment: So you say you checked every (n,k) with n and k from 1 to 4? But plenty of these yield a ratio smaller than -1/5... More importantly, nothing guaratees a priori that other (n,k) would not yield larger or smaller ratios. Whatever.

Comment: Yes, I tried to do it following way: notice, that for some $n, k$ there is supremum, and try to prove it with definition of supremum. If it does not work, how can i  find supremum and infimum of fractions, which are not obvious? Are there any tricky methods?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Denote $f(n,k)=\dfrac{n-k^2}{n^2+k^3}$. When $n,k\in\mathbb{N}$, 
$$f(1,k)=\frac{1-k^2}{1+k^3}\le \frac{1-k^2}{n^2+k^3}\le f(n,k)\le\frac{n-1}{n^2+k^3}\le\frac{n-1}{n^2+1}=f(n,1).$$ 
Then it is easy to find $\sup(A)=\dfrac{1}{5}$ and $\inf(A)=-\frac{1}{3}$.

Comment: How do you find $\frac{1}{5}$? By taking derrivative? Wolphram says, that $max(f(n,1))$ is $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} - \frac{1}{2}$?

Comment: @user46034: It is easy to see $f(2,1)=f(3,1)=\dfrac{1}{5}$ but when  $n>3$, $f(n,1)<\dfrac{1}{5}$. Your maximum $\dfrac{\sqrt{2}-1}{2}$ cannot be achieved by $n\in\mathbb{N}$.